# How to import static cocos library headers to my project(ARC)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, static-libraries

I've static cocos2d library and want to include it into my ARC project. I made cocos2d static library because using it my ARC project...
My projects build but if I want to #import the headers autocomplete shows no option for my static library or cocos.h or something. It's my first try with static libraries.

My workflow:

- Created static library using this tutorial:
  http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/
- I created new workspace
- From finder I draged my main project and project with static library included
- In main project in Build Phases I added my linked library
- In scheme for main project I added my library to targets and checked all checkboxes (run,
  build...)

What else I need to be done? Thanks for help.

---

UPDATE

I read somewhere I need also add Build Phase and Copy headers and add some to Public section. What headers I need to ad there? All cocos2d library or cocos2s.h and cocosdension.h? Or name of my lib??
Here is screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your header search paths in your app settings and see that it's pointing to your static library and headers location (and make it recursive too).

For this, go to to your project, then `Build Settings` and search for `Header Search Paths`. If the path to your headers is missing, then add it (if you work from more than one computer or it's a more-than-one-person project make sure that it's not an absolute path, but relative to the project)

Comment: i'm going to try it, but don't know how to type recursive path. I work only on one computer.
And one more thing, I read somewhere I need also add Build Phase and Copy headers and add some to Public section. What headers I need to ad there? All cocos2d library or cocos2s.h and cocosdension.h? Or name of my lib??

Comment: I'm not sure, because I've never used cocos2d myself, but if there's any .h, you should add it to your project. To make it recursive there's a button on the right side when you are adding the search paths. To make it a relative path to your project, you need to do something like `$(SRCROOT)/cocos2d` (or whatever the folder is called)